# Cannot read a facebook event with graph API from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I ma trying to read facebook event's details from an ANdroid application by using this code :

```
new Request(
                session,
                "me/events/created",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                           System.out.println("Result: " + response.toString());
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

but I m always receiving a ampty response :
Result: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
Although when i tried the Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer i get the right list !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the correct permissions for your app? To get the User's `Events`, you need to aquire the `user_events` permission upon login.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events/#readperms

Comment: In fact i just added this line to my code : loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_events", "friends_events"));

Comment: Good. But remember that all friends_* permissions will not work with Graph API v2.0